# Crystal Reports While Loop through multiple tables

Tags: crystal-reports

What I would like to achieve is checking a date value in one table against a date value in another table and return a third field as a result if it matches. The problem I am experiencing is that the second table has open ended dates. I want the latest to show.

Example:

```
Table_1          Table_2
Serv_Date        Eff_Date   |   Value
12/01/2016       11/01/2016 |   2
                 11/15/2016 |   4
                 01/01/2017 |   5
```

Serv_Date needs to be the closest Eff_Date without going over. So the correct Value in this example would be 4. Table 2 rarely changes and Table 1 has thousands of records so these will vary.

Here is how I thought it should work but it doesn't seem to want to play nice. I was hoping to just get it to pass the correct eff_date and I would have another formula that would compare that and get the correct Value.

```
Local numberVar i := 0;
Local dateVar start := {table1.Serv_Date};
Local dateVar Array eff := {table2.Eff_Date};
Local StringVar output := "";
while (start > eff[i]) do (
  output := output + toText(eff[i]);
);

output;
```

Thank you.

Comment: why don't do this in your database than Crystal Report?

Comment: cache db :/ And unfortunately no access to it. I also hate doing Command connections as they run super slow with cache.

Comment: How do you fetch data in your report, do you have a command or something else? How many records have table1 and table2 in your example?

Comment: Also do you want to show a value for every Eff_Date or to show only one Eff_Date and one value for every Serv_Date (the one closest) ?